# NHibernate Caching Problems

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am having a problem with Nhibernate caching objects and returning old versions:

Here is the code I an running

```
public IList<Foo> GetFoos()
{
  return _session.Query<Foo>().Where(f => f.State == 0).ToList();
}

public void Update(Foo foo)
{
  foo.State = 1;

  _session.Transaction.Begin();
  _session.Update(foo);
  _session.Transaction.Commit();
}
```

If I have 10 Foos in state 0 in the database and I call `GetFoos` I get 10 Foo object which have a state of 0, thats great.

If I call `Update` on every Foo the database shows 10 foos in state 1, thats great.

Now if I call `GetFoos` I get 0 Foo objects, thats great.

If an external application changes the state of all the Foos to state 0, and I run the `GetFoos` method I get 10 objects returned, that's great. However the objects all have a state of 1!!!!!!, thats awful!

Now if I call Update on all the foos, the database doesn't update because Nhibernate thinks nothing has changed, so they stay in state 0 in the database forever.

Have I done something wrong with my configuration, or is this expected behaviour?
How can I get the objects to return the correct, new, values?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The entities loaded by a session (ISession instance) will be kept in first level cache. You can either clear them all (ISession.Clear()) or manually call a ISession.Refresh() on every one to get the current values from the DB.

Comment: I don't understand why if it is using it's cache the GetFoos method would return anything, at least returning nothing would make sense. At the moment a method with the expression `.Where(f.State == 0)` will return objects with `f.State = 1`. Does Nhibernate run the query on the database every time, but return the values from the cache?